# bash: not reading else statement in if..elif statements

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have the following script trying to create a menu using if..elif..else statements. However, my script never run the else statement in the outer while loop while it works in inner while loop? It should echo "try again!" statement on pressing any keys not mentioned in the menu but it exits from the loop. It should only break the loop and exit on pressing "X" key.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ 1 ]]; do

echo 1: menu1
echo 2: menu2
echo 3: menu3
echo X: exit

echo -n enter: ; read menu

if [[ ${menu} -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo menu1
    echo do something in menu1

elif [[ ${menu} -eq 2 ]]; then
    echo menu2
    echo do something in menu2

elif [[ ${menu} -eq 3 ]]; then
    while [[ 1 ]]; do
        echo 11: second menu1
        echo 12: second menu2
        echo 13: exit

        echo -n enter number: ; read second_menu

        if [[ ${second_menu} -eq 11 ]]; then
            echo do something in second menu1
        elif [[ ${second_menu} -eq 12 ]]; then
            echo do something in second menu2
        elif [[ ${second_menu} -eq 13 ]]; then
            break
        else
        echo try again second_menu!
        fi
    done

elif [[ ${menu} -eq 'x' ]] || [[ ${menu} -eq 'X' ]]; then
    break
else
    echo try again menu!
fi
done
```

Comment: its awlays good to add echo-s to see where your program actually exits. try putting an echo in the last elif and then hitting enter see what you get :) Spoiler: code ends up in th last elif, echo-s and breaks

Comment: What were the results of pasting your code into [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)?

Comment: @marxmacher: yes outer while loop breaks on the last elif statement but I don't understand why?

Comment: What are you entering that is not 1,2, or 3?  If you enter a non-digit, then `[[ ${menu} -eq 'x' ]]` is true and gives no helpful error message.  (Trying to avoid my personal rant that `[[` is a bad thing because of its proclivity to hide errors.)

Comment: `echo "do something in second menu1"` `do` is a *command*, enclose in quotes.

Comment: @David C. Rankin `do` is recognized as command only at first position, but not as part of arguments. So quoting is not needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[` is not well behaved.  Consider that `[[ k -eq x ]]` is true, because -eq is an integer comparison and both of those strings evaluate to the integer 0.  (I say it's not well behaved, because good behavior here would generate an error message.)

Use `=` or a case statement or `test` instead of `[[`.  (Personal opinion, avoid `[[` completely.  Its lack of error messages is a travesty, making it totally unusable.)

Comment: I, too, avoid `[[` when I can, which is most of the time.

Comment: I note in passing that Perl uses `!=` for comparing numbers and `-ne` for comparing strings, which is the reverse of what the shell test operators do.  I think Perl has it more sensibly organized — using symbols related to numbers for numeric comparisons, and using alphabetic symbols for alphanumeric comparisons.

Comment: Thank you! It worked on replacing `-eq` with `=` sign. It also works with `-eq` if I use a digit instead of a letter.

Comment: One more problem, if I use `0` in the last `elif` statement with `-eq` to break the loop, it breaks on pressing any key other than mentioned in the menu, again not running the else statement. Is there something special with `0` in bash?
But it works with `=`  sign.

Comment: If you use `-eq`, then `[[ "$menu" -eq 'X' ]]` is true when $menu == 0.  Are you saying the break is executed with menu == 0 and the code is `[[ $menu = 'X' ]]`?

Comment: I changed `[[ "$menu" -eq 'X' ]]` with `[[ "$menu" -eq 0 ]]` in the last elif statement where I am using break statement, then again it doesn't execute `else` statement and break while `-eq` works for other integers (other than 0).

Comment: `[[ "$menu" -eq 0 ]]` will evaluate to true for any non-integer value of `$menu`.  I would strongly recommend getting away from the if/else logic and use a case statement instead.

Comment: Well thank you. I will consider replacing `if..else` with `case` statement.